# Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.PaaSDiagnostics 1.4.1.1 has exited with Exit code: -108

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

After running Azure Diagnostics 2.5 for a period of time, without any problem, it started to fail.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/esWW9bU0) is my wadcfgx.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/vmkikWD0) is the CommandExecution log from the sole instance of the app.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/FkHCjRWL) is my DiagnosticsPluginLauncher log.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/X1B4JEu7) is DiagnosticsPlugin log.

Where is the problem here? 
DiagnosticsPlugin log ends with :

```
DiagnosticsPlugin.exe Error: 0 : [6/3/2015 12:02:41 PM] System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException: The element 'CounterSets' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'CounterSet'.
   at Microsoft.Azure.Plugins.Plugin.BaseMonitoringConfig.Validate(String configFile, String schemaFile)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Plugins.Plugin.WadParser.Translate(String baseMaResourcePath, Int32 actualDiskQuota, String& fullConfigFilePath)
DiagnosticsPlugin.exe Error: 0 : [6/3/2015 12:02:41 PM] Failed to convert WAD1.1 config to Monagent config format
DiagnosticsPlugin.exe Information: 0 : [6/3/2015 12:02:41 PM] DiagnosticPlugin.exe exit with code -108
```

I have humble suggestion - the performance counters set is making the problem. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion was right - trifling with performance counters (a.k.a. selecting my own custom list) is punishable. Disabling them mitigated the problem. I suppose there is a default and allowed (a.k.a. possible) list of performance counters.

[Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics/) is a good article about diagnostics with exhaustive error list and the very good string :

```
%SystemDrive%\ WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.PaaSDiagnostics<DiagnosticsVersion>\CommandExecution.log
```

which made me discover the all the logs needed.

In order to solve similar problems :

1. Publish your instances to staging environment with Remote Desktop enabled.
2. RDP to an instance through the Server Explorer in VS
3. Use the above mentioned folder and discover the logs.
4. Open every log and use it to discover the error with the error code and use the article with the error code suggestions.

Comment: The above is relevant for IaaS, but for PaaS (*cloud services*), we found the logs here: `%SystemDrive%\logs\plugins\`

Comment: This is for PaaS in my case. I do not know about IaaS.